# SSIS: How to programmatically reference child packages?

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package which in turn uses multiple child packages in it with execute package task.
I am trying to run the parent package prorammatically using code similar to the following:

```
Application app = new Application();
Package package = app.LoadPackage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PackagePath"], null);
DTSExecResult results = package.Execute();
```

But when I execute the package I get an exception saying "There is no project to reference". How do I reference the child packages?

Comment: What does `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PackagePath"]` evaluate to?

Comment: Its the file system path of the parent package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to do this using the file system path. But I was able to make it work after deploying the project with the parent and child packages to a SSIS Catalog by using code similar to whats explained in the following link.

http://muxtonmumbles.blogspot.com/2012/08/programmatically-executing-packages-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a ReferenceType of "Project Reference" in your parent SSIS package?  If so, change it to "External Reference", and provide the file path of the package, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193118/running-ssis-execute-package-task-programmactically-error-in-microsoft-sqlserve).